# Flyway can't start from Spring bean

Tags: spring, flyway, jboss-4.2.x

I have a problem and cannot seem to diagnose it.

I am using flyway and spring beans for migrations. Here is sample configuration:

```
<bean id="fib.flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="table" value="FLYWAY_FIB_METATABLE"></property>
    <property name="sqlMigrationPrefix" value="FIB_"></property>
</bean>
```

I build my project with maven then I deploy it on my local Jboss 4.2 server. Everything works fine.

When I push the project to the git repository and hudson runs tests Flyway also behaves as it should. But when it is deployed on server I observe this error:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fib.flyway' defined in class pa
th resource [pl/com/betacom/fib/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Illeg
alStateException: zip file closed
```

Here is log from flyway bean initialization + stackTrace. In the futore I want to use multiple instances of Flyway for different modules of application (that's why classpath scanner discovers more sql files but I think that's not the case).

```
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'fib.flyway'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Creating instance of bean 'fib.flyway'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#1'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#2'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,705 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#3'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,715 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Eagerly caching bean 'fib.flyway' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2013-02-05 12:20:06,721 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,722 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Invoking init method  'migrate' on bean with name 'fib.flyway'
2013-02-05 12:20:06,778 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory] Database: Oracle 10.2
2013-02-05 12:20:06,782 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway] DDL Transactions Supported: false
2013-02-05 12:20:06,784 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway] Schema: TP2
2013-02-05 12:20:06,836 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableTo20FormatUpgrader] No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.0 format necessary
2013-02-05 12:20:06,841 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.metadatatable.MetaDataTableTo202FormatUpgrader] No metadata table upgrade to the Flyway 2.0.2 format necessary
2013-02-05 12:20:06,868 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.FeatureDetector] Spring Jdbc available: true
2013-02-05 12:20:06,873 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Scanning for resources at 'db/migration' (Prefix: 'FIB_', Suffix: '.sql')
2013-02-05 12:20:06,874 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Scanning URL: jar:file:/opt/SabaWeb/JBoss_Tomcat/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp2387195156463610954saba.ear-contents/betacom-custom.jar!/db/migration
2013-02-05 12:20:06,875 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.FeatureDetector] JBoss VFS v2 available: true
2013-02-05 12:20:06,878 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Scanning URL: jar:file:/opt/SabaWeb/JBoss_Tomcat/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp2387195156463610954saba.ear-contents/flex.jar!/db/migration
2013-02-05 12:20:06,878 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Scanning URL: jar:file:/opt/SabaWeb/JBoss_Tomcat/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp2387195156463610954saba.ear-contents/recruitment.jar!/db/migration
2013-02-05 12:20:06,879 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Filtering out resource: db/migration/ (filename: )
2013-02-05 12:20:06,879 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Filtering out resource: db/migration/BC_1.01__Init.sql (filename: BC_1.01__Init.sql)
2013-02-05 12:20:06,879 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Filtering out resource: db/migration/BC_1.02__Finder70992_400.sql (filename: BC_1.02__Finder70992_400.sql)
2013-02-05 12:20:06,879 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Filtering out resource: db/migration/REC_0001__Init_DDL_PCK.sql (filename: REC_0001__Init_DDL_PCK.sql)
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.01__Init_DDL.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.02__Init_pck_fib_pks.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.03__Init_pck_fib_pkb.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.04__Insert_PoollessEmployees_Instance.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.05__Repair.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.06__PoolModifications.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.07__Pool_Modification_pck_fib_pks.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.08__Pool_Modification_pck_fib_pkb.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.09__Pool_Modification_ListOfValues.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,880 DEBUG [com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.scanner.ClassPathScanner] Found resource: db/migration/FIB_1.10__PoolTaking_Constraint_Remove.sql
2013-02-05 12:20:06,916 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fib.flyway' defined in class path resource [pl/com/betacom/fib/dao-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4375)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
    at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:518)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:251)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:204)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:112)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:124)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1163)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1176)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.ClassPathResource.loadAsBytes(ClassPathResource.java:112)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.extractMigrationInfo(SqlMigrationResolver.java:120)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:219)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:157)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:86)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.<init>(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:79)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrator.java:137)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrator.java:133)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:54)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.migration.DbMigrator.migrate(DbMigrator.java:132)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:856)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:820)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1259)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:820)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    ... 154 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in SCM and will come as part of the next release.